# How do I initialise firebase when using context in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I'm trying to follow this tutorial: https://www.robinwieruch.de/complete-firebase-authentication-react-tutorial

I'm getting stuck at this step:

Context.jsx

```
import React from 'react';

const FirebaseContext = React.createContext(null);

export default FirebaseContext;
```

index.js

```
import firebase from "./firebase";
import  FirebaseContext  from './components/firebase/Context';

ReactDOM.render(
  <FirebaseContext.Provider value={new firebase()}>
    <App />
  </FirebaseContext.Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

When I try to implement it, it generates an error that says:

> TypeError: _firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.default is not a
>   constructor

When I google that error message, I get [old posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39397381/react-firebase-googleauthprovider-is-not-a-constructor) which say that the firebase docs have changed in recent years, but the tutorial is more recent than the change.

My firebase.js has:

```
import * as firebase from "firebase";
import firestore from "firebase/firestore";
import 'firebase/auth';

const config = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: ".firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: ".firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: ".appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: ""
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
const database = firebase.database();
const fsDB = firebase.firestore();
const settings = { timestampsInSnapshots: true };

export { firebase,  database as default, fsDB, settings };
```

Does anyone know what to do to get past this problem.

Comment: What is the contents of your `firebase.js`

Comment: @MichelleTilley - I added it above

Comment: You're using `new firebase()` in `index.js` but the object you're exporting as the default in `firebase.js` (the `database` variable) doesn't seem to be a constructor. [In the example, the `Firebase` object is a wrapper around `firebase.initializeApp`](https://github.com/the-road-to-react-with-firebase/react-firebase-authentication/blob/34d1887ecee83af0b3d2a51f4a7c78a55e2dabba/src/components/Firebase/firebase.js#L12-L16), which is not the case in your code, where you're exporting [an instance of `firebase.database.Reference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change this to:

```
import app from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore'
import 'firebase/database';

const config = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: ".firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: ".firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: ".appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: ""
};

class Firebase {
  constructor() {
    app.initializeApp(config);
    this.database = firebase.database();
    this.fsDB = firebase.firestore();
  }
}

export default Firebase
```

Comment: You are not initializing auth anywhere in your original code so there is no need to import it.