# how to login with phone using firebase? i am getting this error message ""reCAPTCHA container is either not found or already contains inner elements!"

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to login user by sending OTP to phone number, but i am getting an error:

> auth.RecaptchaVerifier is not a function

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

here is my code
this is my fire.js file in config folder

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "prokeyy-455bb.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://prokeyy-455bb.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "prokeyy-455bb",
    storageBucket: "prokeyy-455bb.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "602194520114",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: "G-BLY242QNJ3"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  export default firebase
```

and this is my code for otp

```
import firebase from "../config/firebase";
phoneverification(){
        window.recaptchaVerifier=  new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container')
        let number='+91234567'
        var appVerifier = window.recaptchaVerifier;

        firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(number,appVerifier).then(function(e){
let code=prompt('enter opt');
if(code==null){return}
else e.confirm(code).then(function(result){
    console.log(result.user,"user");
    document.querySelector('label').textContent=result.user.phoneNumber+"number is verified"

}).catch(err=>{
    console.log(err);
})

        })
    }
                        <button className="btn btn-primary btn-block" onClick={this.phoneverification}>Sign Up</button>
```

can anyone help me how to fix this error ?

Comment: please supply more information. Where is this code run, what language is it? (please tag the lang).

Comment: in am writing this code in React.js sir

Comment: This is typically caused by a failure to export `firebase` correctly in your `../config/fire` file. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39397381/react-firebase-googleauthprovider-is-not-a-constructor In your case you need something like `firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier`. If you're not able to solve the problem with that, edit your question to also show the (minimal) `../config/fire`.

Comment: a clientside react app, i see, ok. so why are you missing ; at the let recaptcha statement and the let number statement?

Comment: sir i  there is not issue with import fire from "./config/fire" this is fine

Comment: @D.Pardal this firebase config is meant to be published in the clientside code of his app.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen did you find the issue  sir ?@Gewure

Comment: Yes, the issue is the same as what I linked: your `fire` is a `FirebaseApp` instance, while `auth` (without `()`) is only defined on the `firebase` namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you export `fire` from your `config` file, that is a [`firebase.app.App` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.app.App):

const fire=firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export default fire

And the `App` object doesn't have an `auth` property. It **does** have an `auth()` method, but that is not where the `RecaptchaVerifier` is defined.

You will need to import the `firebase` namespace properly into your main JavaScript. You can do that by either exporting it correctly from your `config` file:

```
export default firebase
```

You may have to change some of your main code in that case, to adapt to the new export/import. Alternatively you can import the `firebase` namespace in your main file too:

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
```

This can live side-by-side with your existing import, as far as I can see.

In either case, you'll then need to refer to `auth` namespace and its `RecaptchaVerifier` as shown in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth#use-the-recaptcha-widget):

```
new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container');
```

Comment: sir by doing that i am getting this message "reCAPTCHA container is either not found or already contains inner elements!" ......i also modified the code above as per your instructions

Comment: Since the error message changed, you original problem (which had to do with how you import the `firebase` object) is gone. I recommend opening a new question for the new problem, which seems more related to your HTML.